# PyTorch: get input layer size

Tags: pytorch

I want to programatically find the size of my input layer.

If my first layer is called `fc1`, how do I find out its input?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your model is called `model`, this will give the number of input features of the `fc1` layer:

```
model.fc1.in_features
```

This is useful inside the `.forward()` method:

```
def forward(self, x):
    x = x.view(-1, self.fc1.in_features)  # resize the input to match the input layer
    ...
```